# GridView onTap is only called during creation

Tags: dart, flutter

I made a GridView with children that each has a `GestureDetector` and a `onTap` method set. But the onTap event gets called only when the view is created and not when the item has been tapped. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class MyGridView extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
              child: new GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  children: [
                    new GridItem(0),
                    new GridItem(1)
                  ]
              )
          )
        ]
    );
  }
}

class GridItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int code;
  GridItem(this.code);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
        onTap: print(code),
        child: new Container(
            height: 48.0,
            child: new Text('$code')
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want:

`onTap: () { print(code); },`

What you're doing is calling print, then saving the return value from print (which will be a null) as the onTap handler, which actually disables the onTap handler. If you see anything in the logs it'll be from the time you actually did the build, not when you tapped.